Docker build is slow on AWS EC2 even if all layers are cached
I have a Dockerfile that builds on my local PC in a few seconds when all layers are cached. But when I run the same in the pipeline in an AWS EC2 instance, it runs for 8 minutes. I can see that all layers are cached in the job log. The instance specs: t3a.xlarge with 4 vCPU and 16GB memory. The volume specs: 200GB, gp3, 3000 IOPS, 250 MBps throughput. The instance memory usage is up to 30%, CPU usage is up to 60%, the volume usage is up to 300 IOPS. What can be the issue here?
Update: I've recreated the EC2 instance where the Docker is running and the issue has gone. On the old one, I tried docker system prune -a but it didn't help. So it looks like the issue accumulates over time. Why? And how to prevent it in the future? Docker version is 20.10.23.
